# 2d slice through a 3d matrix created from a binary data file

Tags: matlab, 3d, data-visualization

I have a cfd fortran code which outputs results files into binary results file. I have imported the binary file into matlab and read and reshaped it into a 3d matrix. the code to do this is below:

```
% function [rtime,itime,dt,nx,ny,nz,deltax,deltay,rlenz,rw] = Read_press3d(press.420000)
% _________________________________________________________________________
% name;
fid    = fopen('press.420000', 'rb');
% fid;
rtime  = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
itime  = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
dt     = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
nx0    = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
ny0    = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
nz     = fread(fid, 1,          'int32');
deltax = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
deltay = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
rlenz  = fread(fid, 1,          'float64');
rwtoto  = fread(fid, nx0*ny0*nz, 'float64');
fclose(fid);

rw = reshape(rwtoto,[nx0,ny0,nz]);
% v = reshape(vtoto,[nx0,ny0,nz]);
% w = reshape(wtoto,[nx0,ny0,nz]);

% u = utoto(1:)
% lag  = toto1(1:nx0-1,1:ny0-1)';
% dudn = toto2(1:nx0-1,1:ny0-1)';
% 
% % valxy(ny0,:) = valxy(1,:);
% % valxy(:,nx0) = valxy(:,1);

nx = nx0-1;
ny = ny0-1;
```

Here, `rw` is the reshaped pressure in a single `257x512x390` array. Now I want to view the pressure in this 3D array as a contour plot or visualise it in another useful way. I know that one way is to create a 2d slice at different locations in the y-z plane, so along the `512x390`.

I have tried to use the `slice` function, but cannot figure out how to make it work. I only have the values of the pressure stored in the 3d array. I don't have the corresponding x,y,z locations, but the lengths of the array are based upon delta x,y,z, so actually the size of my 3d array should correspond to the coordinates.

Any help on how to draw a slice or any other way to visualise the data will be most welcome.

Comment: have a look at [`isosurface`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's `imagesc` function is one of the better ways I've come across for visualizing 2D matrices. If the x-dimension of your 3D array is the time axis, Then you can loop through the 2D matrices in the yz-plane and plot them in color using `imagesc`, like so:

```
for i = 1:size(rw,1)
    pressure = rw(i,:,:);    % Extract the ith pressure matrix
    imagesc(pressure)        % Plot in color
    pause(0.1)               % Pause execution for 10th of second for viewing
end
```